# DocuSign: Is there a way to set custom fields in the document in a template and then later replace with unique values while creating the envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

What I want is to place the custom fields at document level while creating the template so that later I can have unique values for every envelope that is created. These values should be visible to all the recipients.

These are the steps that I currently follow:

1. Create Document Custom Fields/Tab Definitions at the Account level.
2. Create the template from our app and navigate to DocuSign to place the above created custom fields on the document (it is signer specific).
3. Save the template.

At a later stage, choose the template in our app and create an envelope with the template ID, templateRoles (with custom fields' values for signer), status etc. like below:

```
{
    "templateId": "1e6c1118-1234-1244-1244-c4a11111775b",
    "templateRoles": [
            {
                "roleName": "Signer1",
                "name": "Signer1",
                "email": "Signer1@Signer1.com",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Account.Name",
                            "value": "account-name777"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.FullName",
                            "value": "candidate-name1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.Mobile",
                            "value": "0412347777"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "roleName": "Signer2",
                "name": "Signer2",
                "email": "Signer2@Signer2.com",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Account.Name",
                            "value": "account-name777"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.FullName",
                            "value": "candidate-name1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.Mobile",
                            "value": "0412347777"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

The above works for Signer1 but does not show the custom fields' values to Signer2. The custom fields need to be exactly the same for all recipients. Is there a way to achieve this?

Also what I noticed was after Signer1 signs the document then the custom fields' values show to Signer2.

Comment: can you have different tabLabels? for each signer? you can still use the same values, but if you change the tabLabels to be unique - I think it will fix it

Comment: The tabs are exactly the same for all signers. I will have to place the tabs at the same position for all signers. I tried this out. Once all the signers finish signing then the end document looks messy.

Comment: they can still be in the same position, all I asked what to change the tabLabel. How does this make the document messy?

Comment: Can't have different tab labels for every signer. I can place the same tab label for each signer at the exact same position. But then for some reason after one of the signers is done signing and the second signer opens the document, the tabs' text overlaps and becomes bolder and looks fuzzy.

Comment: why can't you have a different label? how are you generating the template? you can change it to have different labels.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of what you mean through the API calls?

Comment: it's too long for here, let me answer below

Answer (score 0):

Change the tabLabels so they are not the same, here is the code:

```
{
    "templateId": "1e6c1118-1234-1244-1244-c4a11111775b",
    "templateRoles": [
            {
                "roleName": "Signer1",
                "name": "Signer1",
                "email": "Signer1@Signer1.com",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Account.Name1",
                            "value": "account-name777"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.FullName1",
                            "value": "candidate-name1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.Mobile1",
                            "value": "0412347777"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "roleName": "Signer2",
                "name": "Signer2",
                "email": "Signer2@Signer2.com",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Account.Name2",
                            "value": "account-name777"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.FullName2",
                            "value": "candidate-name1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "Candidate.Mobile2",
                            "value": "0412347777"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```